# Get angle in terms of 360 degrees

Tags: javascript, geometry, angle

I would like to get an angle in terms of 360 degrees... for my game, I need to know which direction the player is heading in...

[image]

The code here gets the proper angles, but only in terms of 90 degree increments: (meaning, when I click in upper left quadrant, I get angle from 0 to 90 degrees... bottom left is 0 to -90 degrees, etc...)

[image]

```
    var dY = this.pos.y-e.gameY;            //opposite
    var dX = this.pos.x-e.gameX;            //adjacent
    var dist = Math.sqrt((dY*dY)+(dX*dX));  //hypotenuse
    var sin = dY/dist;                      //opposite over hypotenuse
    var radians = Math.asin(sin);
    var degrees = radians*(180/Math.PI);    //convert from radians to degrees
    this.calculatedAngle = degrees;
```

How can I get it in terms of 360 degrees?

---

Here is another example: The top two represent the issue... when I click in the upper/lower left quadrant, it keeps drawing a right triangle from the x axis...

I need it to be like the lower 2 pictures, where it keeps drawing the angle around:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any data that can be used to demonstrate your calculations in all 4 quadrants?

Comment: You can use the sign of `dy` and `dx` to distinguish the quadrant and add an offset to your result accordingly.

Comment: @Xotic750 What do you mean? I simply take the point on the map the user clicks on (e.gameX or e.gameY) and get the distance to the current location of the player. Orange, I also don't really understand what you mean

Comment: So is the origin on your diagrams at (0, 0)? And all of your values are relative to that origin? So examples for both player and click  would be like (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1) and (1, -1). I.e. the player could be at (1, 1) and get a click at (2, 2), or is the player always at (0, 0) and the click elsewhere?

Comment: @Xotic750 they are not. They are simply coordinates of the player vs the clickpoint on the screen. So the player could be at (200, 300), click at (400, 500), and the distX = 200, distY = 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a little bit more information than just the arcsin to figure this out. The reason for this is that arcsin will only return values between -π/2 and π/2 (-90 degrees and 90 degrees), as you already know.

So, to figure out the other part, you need to be aware of what quadrant you are in.

[image]

In quadrant 2, arcsin is between 90 and 0, the real angle is between 90 and 180. So if you are in quadrant 2, 180-`calculated angle`=`real angle`. `(180-90=90, 180-0=180)`.

In quadrant 3, arcsin is between 0 and -90. The real angle is between 180 and 270. so again, 180-`calculated angle` = `real angle`. `(180-0=180, 180-(-90)=270)`.

In quadrant 4, arcsin is between -90 and 0. The real angle is between 270 and 360. So 360+`calculated angle`=`real angle`. `(360+(-90)=270, 360+0)=360)`.

The same is also true for quadrant 1, you just don't need to make the transformation. (`0+360=360 (equivalent to 0), 90+360=450 (equivalent to 90) )`.

So, determine the quadrant first, and apply a rule based on that. 
For an (x,y) coordinate, if x is positive and y is positive, you are quadrant 1. If x is negative and y is positive, you are quadrant 2. If x is negative and y is negative, you are quadrant 3. if x is positive and y is negative, you are quadrant 4.

So in your case, the distance from the origin is you `(dX,dY)` coordinate pair, so something like this should do it:

```
//your original code...
var degrees = radians*(180/Math.PI);    //convert from radians to degrees

//then


if (dX>=0 and dY>=0)
{//quadrant 1
//no transformation, do nothing
}
if (dX>=0 and dy<0) 
{ //quadrant 4
degrees=360+degrees;
}
if (dX<0 and dy<0) 
{ //quadrant 3
degrees=180-degrees;
}
if (dX<0 and dy>0) 
{ //quadrant 2
degrees=180-degrees;
}


this.calculatedAngle = degrees;
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do this directly from the coordinates, without computing extra information like the hypotenuse, by using the [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function, which was designed in the early days of FORTRAN for situations exactly like yours.

Note two important things:

1. that the `atan2` function has been created to automatically handle *all but one case* of the many possible cases, and
2. it will output a range of `(-PI, PI]`.

The case where both coordinates are (0, 0) is left undefined (all angles are equivalent when the magnitude of a vector is zero), so I'm arbitrarily setting the angle to zero degrees in that case. And in order to obtain the desired range, some simple logic and addition is needed.

```
var Vx = this.pos.x - e.gameX;
var Vy = this.pos.y - e.gameY;

var radians;

if (Vx || Vy) {
    radians = Math.atan2(Vy, Vx);
} else {
    radians = 0;
}

if (radians < 0) {
    radians += 2*Math.PI;
}

var degrees = radians * 180 / Math.PI;

this.calculatedAngle = degrees;
```

The result will be an angle defined for all cases and within the range [0, 360°), as desired.

#### Example

```js
function showDegrees(e, svg) {
 var rectangle = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
 var targetX = (rectangle.left + rectangle.right)/2;
 var targetY = (rectangle.top + rectangle.bottom)/2;
 var Vx = Math.round(e.clientX - targetX);
 var Vy = Math.round(targetY - e.clientY);
 var radians = Math.atan2(Vy, Vx);
 if (radians < 0) radians += 2*Math.PI;
 var degrees = Math.round(radians*180/Math.PI);
 var textBox = document.getElementById('showdegrees');
 textBox.innerHTML = degrees + '&deg;' + ' (' + Vx + ', ' + Vy + ')';
 textBox.setAttribute('x', Math.round(100 + Vx));
 textBox.setAttribute('y', Math.round(100 - Vy));
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" onmousemove="showDegrees(evt, this)">
<text x="0" y="0" fill="red" style="font-size: 12px"  id="showdegrees">Info</text>
<line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1" />
<line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 1" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```js
var dY = this.pos.y - e.gameY,          // opposite
    dX = this.pos.x - e.gameX,          // adjacent
    radians = Math.atan(dY/dX);         // wrong, in [-1/2 pi, 1/2 pi]
if(1/dX < 0) radians += Math.PI;        // fixed, in [-1/2 pi, 3/2 pi]
if(1/radians < 0) radians += 2*Math.PI; // fixed, in [+0, 2 pi]
var degrees = radians*180/Math.PI;      // from radians to degrees
```

Explanation:

- Better calculate the radians with `Math.atan` and the tangent. Calculating the hypotenuse using `Math.sqrt` is expensive.
- `Math.atan` gives an angle between `-1/2 pi` and `1/2 pi`, that is, the right half circle. To fix it, just sum `pi` in case `dX` was negative.
- Then we get an angle between `-1/2 pi` and `3/2 pi`. So, in case it's negative, we sum `2 pi` in order to obtain an angle between `0` and `2 pi`.
- Note that we must consider `-0` negative in order to make it work properly. So, instead of checking `dX < 0` and `radians < 0`, we check their inverse.
- Note the final result will be `NaN` in case both `dX` and `dY` are `0` (or `-0`).